# Planner is not working for Baxter simulator in Rviz and with Moveit

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed Baxter and Moveit simulator to work with Baxter as said [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/325925/how-to-use-baxter-in-simulation-with-rviz-and-moveit/).
However, I am having an issue, the planner is neither working in Rviz if I just drag the interactive marker and then plan nor if I run [this](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/scripts/doc/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html) tutorial. It keeps failing when I drag the marker in Rviz and then plan and when I run the tutorial code, it keeps saying no motion plan found.

My PC also hangs after running the Gazebo and Rviz together for about 5 minutes, it has 16 gigabytes of RAM with a core i7 processor. So, capacity of the computer should not be an issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326210/planner-is-not-working-for-baxter-simulator-in-rviz-and-with-moveit/) by [Tawfiq Chowdhury](https://answers.ros.org/users/39656/tawfiq-chowdhury/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2019-06-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tawfiq Chowdhury](https://answers.ros.org/users/39656/tawfiq-chowdhury/) on 2019-06-18**:
@Geoff could you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out, after running the commands from Baxter [simulator](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Simulator_Installation) tutorial, you first need to run the following commands in two separate terminals from [this](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/MoveIt_Tutorial) tutorial :

```
rosrun baxter_tools enable_robot.py -e
rosrun baxter_interface joint_trajectory_action_server.py
```

Then you need to select command "With Electric Gripper(s)" and run the following command:

```
roslaunch baxter_moveit_config baxter_grippers.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [Tawfiq Chowdhury](https://answers.ros.org/users/39656/tawfiq-chowdhury/) with karma: 137 on 2019-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0